# Is there a way to edit the username under five characters on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

For example, look at this image below :

[image]

This user has a username of just two characters: `mf`.

Are there any tricks involved for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no tricks to this. These users are of the following type

- Business pages with $$$
- Facebook employees
- Famous people
- Past Facebook employees

Your username cannot be shorter than 5 characters unless you are part of this group.